# How to search with radio Button in c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

[**Table Form**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1HF9.png)

I'm trying to filter this table with RadioButton when **DateDePublication** is **Checked** and the value of the **search text** equals for example 2000 table should return all books who have **DateDePublication** equals to 2000

this is Search Button code :

```
private void RechBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = repository.GetAllLivres(rechtext.Text);

        }
```

and search method code to return all books :

```
public List<Livre> FilterDateDePublication(string date)
    {
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            var livres = new List<Livre>();
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            connection.Open();
            var command = factory.CreateCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select * from livre where date_publication like '%" + date + "%'";
            using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Livre l = new Livre();
                    l.Isbn = reader["isbn"].ToString();
                    l.Titre = reader["titre"].ToString();
                    l.DatePublication = DateTime.Parse(reader["date_publication"].ToString());
                    l.NombrePage = Int32.Parse(reader["nombre_page"].ToString());
                    l.Couverture = reader["couverture"].ToString();
                    l.Prix = Double.Parse(reader["nombre_page"].ToString());
                    l.QuantiteDisponible = Int32.Parse(reader["quantite_disponible"].ToString());
                }
            }
            return livres;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your function GetAllLivres just looks for books with a specifc string in their title.

```
command.CommandText = "select * from livre where titre like '%" + mc + "%'";
```

You should change that to search on the pub date. Can says how that should look because we dont know your database scheme.

By the way , do not build SQL like that, its a huge security hole. Use parametrized queries

Comment: I have changed my function Get AllLivres to FilterDateDePublication but i don't know how to make it search for just books that published in 2000 using radio button. and thanks for the tip i will look into that.

Comment: @AbderrahmaneRadiohead what does 'search with a radio button' mean? You search with functions, radio button is a UI widget

Comment: I know i have 4 radio buttons when one of them is checked Search function should look up by each of radio button.

Comment: Thank you its worked i had a typo in my second function FilterDateDePublication that's why didn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

> I know i have 4 radio buttons when one of them is checked Search function should look up by each of radio button.

Well again not seeing the UI its hard to say but my guess is you have something like this

```
   |-search by: --------| <<< group box
   | ( ) Author         |  << radio buttons
   | ( ) title          |
   | (*) Year           |
   ----------------------
   Search for :_________________: <<== text box
   [Start Search]                 <<== button
```

I hope so.

So do this

```
 if(radioYear.Checked){
        FilterDateDePublication(searchText.Text);
 }
 else if(radioAuthor.Checked)
    .......
```

Note that the date the user enters might not match the format of the date in the database, in that case you need to do some massaging

I would however refactor your code, you have surely noticed that 90% of your FilterDateDePublication is the same as the title one.

You should do

```
public List<Livre> ReadBooks(string query)
{
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        var livres = new List<Livre>();
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        var command = factory.CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = query;
        using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Livre l = new Livre();
                l.Isbn = reader["isbn"].ToString();
                l.Titre = reader["titre"].ToString();
                l.DatePublication = DateTime.Parse(reader["date_publication"].ToString());
                l.NombrePage = Int32.Parse(reader["nombre_page"].ToString());
                l.Couverture = reader["couverture"].ToString();
                l.Prix = Double.Parse(reader["nombre_page"].ToString());
                l.QuantiteDisponible = Int32.Parse(reader["quantite_disponible"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return livres;

    }
```

and then have

```
   List<Livre> GetByDate(string date){
        return GetBooks("select * from livre where date_publication like '%" + date + "%'";

    }
```

even better would be to use sql parameters. I will update this answer later

Comment: I have already attached a picture of UI at the top of post, I tried to ``` if(radioYear.Checked){
        FilterDateDePublication(searchText.Text);
 }
 else if(radioAuthor.Checked)` ``and I modified Readbook function when i check radio button and write in search it return nothing

Comment: @AbderrahmaneRadiohead then you should ignore all the UI stuff first and get the db search running. In my last line I point out that you have to supply a date in the correct format.